Walletconnect (Reown) network configuration?
Apologies for any stupid questions, I am fairly new to programming
I am following documentation from Reown to implement their appkit into my project
https://docs.reown.com/appkit/react/core/installation
I've installed all necessary libraries, but to add networks it imports network configs from here:
import { arbitrum, mainnet } from '@reown/appkit/networks';
But I don't have this directory, anyone have experience with Reown and walletconnect?
I've tried lots of different ways using wagmi core and other methods but no such luck

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
